# How to get a value for key with an index? NSDict (Objective C)

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, foundation

I have a `nsdictionary` which has 2 keys: "`frontCard", "flipCard"`.

Now I want to put all values for the key "`frontCard`" into a `nsarray` and all values for the key "`flipCard`" into a seperate `nsarray`.

How can I do that?

Comment: How is the data in "frontCard" and "flipCard" separated? Commas, whitespaces, ... ?

Comment: I just made this: [myDict setValue: @"mystring" forKey:@"frontCard"]; and for the flipCard too

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean?

```
NSArray *frontCardArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[myDict valueForKey:@"frontCard"]];
NSArray *flipCardArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[myDict valueForKey:@"flipCard"]];
```

//EDIT: and just to make sure. If you set a value and then another:

```
[myDic setValue:@"1" forKey:@"frontCard"];
[myDic setValue:@"2" forKey:@"frontCard"];
```

the key "frontCard" would NOT contain both! the "2" would overwrite the "1". You can only have one value in one key. OR you can save an array into a dictionary:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
[myDic setValue:myArray forKey:@"frontCard"];
```